# Javascript + Youtube API

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

can someone explain me how to get video URL from Youtube API

There is the link i have to scan firstly.

> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/K8ijg73GqrMLt5klQTDW1g/uploads/?max-results=1

It will give me big code, and I have to take url=''; from this piece of code:

```
<media:content url='https://www.youtube.com/v/o0n8tDS_pjM?version=3&amp;f=user_uploads&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='100' yt:format='5'/>
```

Okay. So I have to take this

> url='https://www.youtube.com/v/o0n8tDS_pjM?

And put it as variable to this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/v/o0n8tDS_pjM?"></iframe>
```

But I don't know how exactly to do this in JavaScript, or JQuery. But I will apreaciete, if you could help me with my problem.

Exactly i need to get lastest video from YouTube API and show it on my websites in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

to embed a video, the correct url is https://www.youtube.com/embed/code

example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o0n8tDS_pjM?"></iframe>
```

there's an example http://jsfiddle.net/5wt37ns0/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change the URL you use, adding &alt=json makes the data json and fare easier to process

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/K8ijg73GqrMLt5klQTDW1g/uploads/?max-results=1&alt=json
```

Now that we are getting JSON it's far easier to process the data returned

Html:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" allowfullscreen id="frame"></iframe>
```

Now the javascript function:

```
$.getJSON("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/K8ijg73GqrMLt5klQTDW1g/uploads/?max-results=1&alt=json", function(data) {
    $("#frame").attr("src","//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/"+ data.feed.entry[0].id.$t.split("/")[6])
})
```

I have tested this in codepen

1. http://codepen.io/MaxJP/full/jErRZz/ (Full screen)
2. http://codepen.io/MaxJP/pen/jErRZz?editors=101 (Code)

Comment: I don't know it is not working for me. even if i copy code, it is not working.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it is working, but only on online server. In my computer it is not working, i guess it's because i don't have jquerry downloaded.

Comment: You need jquery for it to work, but if you need it I can do it in normal JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Simple like this: .split() function

```
'https://www.youtube.com/v/o0n8tDS_pjM?version=3&amp;f=user_uploads&amp;app=youtube_gdata'.split('?')[0]
"https://www.youtube.com/v/o0n8tDS_pjM"
```